# buscar y reemplazar un valor por una 'X' en python

Tags: python, array

necesito que el código al comprar un boleto de avión y luego consultar de nuevo los pasajes me cambie el numero por una 'X' para saber cuales están ocupados y cuales no, pero lo que llevo de estudio no puedo buscar una solución buena y si alguna de sus soluciones cambia algo más en el código no importa(como añadir otro array o quitar uno), por ejemplo yo tengo una duda de que si realmente es necesario hacer las 2 filas por que me piden que luego los asientos de 36 a 42 sean VIP ósea que paguen mas pero aun no puedo llegar a esa parte del código por que no puedo avanzar en reemplazar el valor que ingrese el usuario como asiento

```
import numpy as np, pprint as pp, math as m
bancoduoc = True
x = 0
opcion = 0
pago_pasaje = 0
lista_p= []
fila1 = np.array((
    [1, 2, 3],
    [7, 8, 9],
    [13, 14, 15],
    [19, 20, 21],
    [25, 26, 27],
    [31, 32, 33], 
    [37, 38, 39] 
    ))
fila2 = np.array((
    [4, 5, 6],
    [10, 11 ,12],
    [16, 17, 18],
    [22, 23 ,24],
    [28, 29, 30],
    [34, 35 ,36],
    [40, 41, 42]
    ))
asientos = [fila1,fila2]
while opcion != 5:

    if(opcion == 1):
        print('Elegiste ver los asientos disponibles')
        for i in range(7):
            for k in range(3):
                print(fila1[i][k], fila2[i][k])

    if(opcion == 2):
        print('Elegiste comprar un asiento')
        print('le vamos a pedir unos datos para completar su pago')

        nombrePasajero = input('Ingrese su nombre: ')
        if nombrePasajero == str:
            print('Nombre ingresado correctamente')
            lista_p.append(nombrePasajero)
        
        while True:
            try:
                rutPasajero = (input('Ingrese su rut: '))
                lista_p.append(rutPasajero)
                break
            except:
                print('carácter inválido')

        while True:   
            try:
                telefonoPasajero = int(input('Ingrese su telefono: '))
                if telefonoPasajero >= 100000000 and telefonoPasajero <= 999999999:
                            print("Teléfono válido.")
                            lista_p.append(telefonoPasajero)
                            break
                else:
                    print('vuelva a intentarlo')
            except:
                print('carácter inválido')
        while True:
            try:
                opcion_banco = int(input('¿es usted usuario de BancoDUOC?\n1.-Si \n2.-No\n : '))
                if opcion_banco == 1:
                    print('como usted es usuario va a tener un descuento en el pasaje')
                    bancoduoc == True
                    break
                else:
                    print('ingrese una opción válida')
                if opcion_banco == 2:
                    print('usted no va a tener descuento en el pasaje')
                    bancoduoc == False
                    break
                else:
                    print('ingrese una opción válida')
            except:
                print('carácter inválido')

        tipo_asiento = int(input('que tipo de asiento desea? el asiento VIP tiene un costo de $240.000 mientras que el normal solo $78.900\n 1.-Normal \n 2.-VIP\n :'))
        if (tipo_asiento == 1):
            fila = int(input('ingrese una fila, las opciones son\n .-Fila 1\n .-Fila 2\n :  '))
            if (fila == 1):
                print('los asientos disponibles en la fila 1 son: ')
                for i in range(7):
                    for k in range(3):
                        print( fila1[i][k] )
                asiento = int(input("ingrese la posicion del asiento: "))-1
                if asiento in range(len(fila1)):
                    fila1[fila == asiento] = 0
                    print("Listo!")

    if(opcion == 3):
        print('Vuelva pronto')
        break
    try:
        opcion = int(input("Ingrese la opción\n1.-Ver asientos disponibles\n2.-Comprar asientos\n3.-Salir\n : "))
    except:
        print('opción invalida')
        opcion = 0
```

Comment: Si usas numpy array no puedes cambiar su tipo de variable

Comment: Veo que has hecho una pregunta muy parecida (casi similar) y tiene 2 respuestas, considera aceptar una o dejar un comentario diciendo que es lo que no soluciona.